# "That don't make your place safe" grammer

Tags: grammar, present-tense

Strangely, in Amy Winehouse' song "In my bed" there's a line in the chorus which goes:

> So sorry if I turn my head
>  Yours is a familiar face
>  But **that don't
>   make** your place safe

Obviously, "that" is like "it" and should be followed by "doesn't".

Is this a bold grammatical mistake? some extremely regional British* way to conjugate verbs? or maybe simply a style thing, to give the song more "colloquial" feeling"?

[A link to the song itself (it's from her Vevo so it's legal to share)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdi_yuSgQw8)
[a link to the lyrics](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/amywinehouse/inmybed.html)

*although the song itself is sung with an American accent.

Comment: It's just a colloquial use of nonstandard grammar. The lyrics you provide contain many grammatical and spelling mistakes; 'Your still clinging' 'seperate' and so on.

Comment: @KateBunting given lyrics aside, this is what she actually sings. I wonder where is that colloquial use is used, as I never heard myself people use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Don't" as a third-person singular verb form is common in many non-standard varieties of English around the globe. Now they are all frowned on socially, but in the 1880's the playwright W S Gilbert put "It don't" and "he don't" in the mouths of upper class characters.